# Deselecting the table view row when returning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios

I followed Luke Redpath's suggestion here - [Selected UItableViewCell staying blue when selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803061/selected-uitableviewcell-staying-blue-when-selected) - to deselect the row when returning to the original table view, but I can't get it working. In fact the method doesn't get triggered.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}
```

I suspect this is because the class isn't a `UITableViewController`, but a `UIViewController` with the `tableView` as a property connected up to the NIB.

How would I get the same behavior - ie deselecting when returning?

Comment: It shouldn't matter as long as the tableView is hooked up correctly.  You should be able to put it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and have it work.  You also might want to do a quick NSLog check of what `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` returns since it might actually be returning nil.

Comment: I used this but had an issue where changing things in the cell (background etc) wasn't reflected immediately. Adding reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: in didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: did the trick

Answer (score 21):

why you just don't deselect it in the delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: You don't have to do `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]`, indexPath is already a parameter, and you can just insert it there.

Comment: Also, if you're using the delegate method, you should use the `tableView` parameter instead of `self.tableView`, because they could potentially be different if you have multiple tableviews.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using a NavigationController, you can do it with its delegate:

```
- (void)navigationController: (UINavigationController *)navigationController
       didShowViewController: (UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated: (BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}
```

But you have to check whether the show controller is which you want =/

[EDIT]
Create the outlet and link it in IB to NavigationController

```
@interface MyInt <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigation;
    ...
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigation;
...
@end

@implementation MyInt
@syntesize navigation;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigation setDelegate: self];
}
...

@end
```

Comment: My nav controller is created in my nib, so it has no corresponding class. Is there way around this?

Comment: You can map it to an IBOutlet ivar.

Comment: My setup is that I've got a MainViewController class with a corresponding NIB. That nib has UITabBarController (also an IBOutlet property 'tabBarController' in MainViewController). Within that tab bar are several UINavigation controllers. These are not referenced in code. So I am not sure how to access any of these nav controllers

Answer (score 8):

Are you selecting the row programmatically? If so, I had the same problem when selecting a row using `[cellToBeSelected setSelected:YES];`.

By using the `UITableViewController`'s `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` method it kept track of the current selected indexPath.

In fact, if `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` is set to true, one does not have deselect rows manually.

Answer (score 8):

I hade the same problem, but after debugging I found out the indexPathForSelectedRow count was 0 so I double checked my code and noticed I was calling

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // some code...
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

After deleting this line it just worked as expected.

Comment: This was a completely obvious mistake that caught me. I think lots of people including myself put the deselect in the delegate out of habit.

Answer (score 4):

**Very simple :** Try this line.

Add `deselectRowAtIndexPath` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    //Write Your Other code Here.
            }
```

It Will deselect Row after you click on It.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Comment: Please describe why this is the solution. What is the change/trick?